# How to cancel software upgrade

Tags: upgrade, apt, wine

When I turned my computer on today, I opened a terminal and ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But I read on OMG! Ubuntu that the latest version of Wine, 1.3.25, ["breaks audio playback for Windows apps"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/latest-wine-update-breaks-pulseaudio/). I obviously didn't want to break sound in my games, so I decided I had to keep the old 1.3.24 version until the problem was fixed. I didn't know how to stop the software upgrade, so I just pressed Ctrl+Z while it was downloading the new version. What should I do now?

Comment: I **Strongly** suggest you to read the comments there.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+Z will only push the process to the background. It might still be running. type `fg` to bring the process to the foreground. As Uri says, read the comments on the page, there *might* be some solution mentioned. And just FYI, Ctrl+C will stop the command.

Comment: They said something about Wine-pulse but I don't want to apply any patches or use special versions of Wine, I just want to keep using wine-1.3.24 until the problem is fixed. I typed `fg` and then pressed Ctrl+C as @Kaustubh P said. If I go to Synaptic and lock the current version, will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If depend that you have de ppa of wine, if you dont have dont worry Ubuntu only upgrade the stable version of Wine.

In case that you have the ppa of wine, you have desactive in origen of software.

Comment: I'm using the PPA, but I think that would work. Thank you!